# Remove the 1px border under UISearchBar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, uikit, uisearchbar

[image: UISearchBar 1px black border]

I'm having trouble removing that 1px border directly under the UISearchBar view. Now it doesn't look matched up with my done button view. I've tried:

```
searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 0;
searchBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0;
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps it's part of the design?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Nevermind, I just did:

```
searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1;
searchBar.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
```

and it works!

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I don't get any options when I try autocomplete after searchBar.layer.
Any ideas why?

Comment: OK, I had to: #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: The only reason why it worked is because you set the border color to your view's background color. But it's the best solution I found so far.

Comment: Works for me, but I had to put it in the viewWillAppear method.

Comment: for matching background color, searchBar.layer.borderColor = searchBar.barTintColor.CGColor;

Answer (score 53):

```
[searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]];
```

Comment: I think this is a iOS 7+ solution, which is what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: This depends on the background color you are using.

Answer (score 25):

For **Swift** version, tested on iOS9:

```
searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

It would show like this:

[image: no-border-result]

Comment: I spend almost 4 hours. Finally, I found a perfect solution. Thank you.

Comment: still works on ios 15 and swift 5

Answer (score 4):

In order to overcome this in Xamarin Forms, you'll need to create a `CustomRenderer` to the `SearchBar` class.
Like this:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using MyProject.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SearchBar), typeof(CustomSearchBarRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.iOS
{
    public class CustomSearchBarRenderer:SearchBarRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.SearchBar> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);
            if (this.Control == null) return;

            this.Control.BackgroundImage = new UIKit.UIImage ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works and why the more simple answers aren't good enough?