# Swift: How to change tableHeaderView's border color programatically in a tableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I try to change the headerView's border color to surfing green, but it seems that my code does not work. What I tried is this:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 105.0/255.0, green: 215.0/255.0, blue: 189.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
tableView.tableHeaderView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

However, the header's border still looks like this:

[Here is the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8E7M.png) (Sorry I do not have enough reputation to post images)

As you can see, the border is still black/deep blue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with border between navigation bar and search bar...

check on [this link for solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631567/remove-border-between-view-and-search-bar)

```
searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

some example to change border:

```
searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1 
searchBar.layer.borderColor = someColor.CGColor
```