# Removing the blank spaces on left and right side of the UISearchBar

Tags: ios, autolayout, uisearchbar, layout-anchor, nslayoutanchor

I am creating a UI component that should display a `UILabel` and a `UISearchBar` below.

However, I am not able to align them, the `UISearchBar` always has extra space on both left and right side (highlighted RED).

I was trying to set the dimensions of `searchBarTextField` by layout anchors directly, but it didn't work.

I would prefer to do it using layout anchors when possible.

`SearchBar.m`:

```
-(id) init {        
    self.titleLabel = [UILabel new];
    self.searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar;
    UIView *searchBarWrapper = [UIView new];

    [self.view addSubview:self.titleLabel];
    [self.view addSubview:searchBarWrapper];
    [searchBarWrapper addSubview:self.searchBar];

    [self.titleLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [searchBarWrapper setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.searchBar setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    //[self.titleLabel.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.widthAnchor multiplier:1.0].active = YES;
    [self.titleLabel.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:14.0].active = YES;
    [self.titleLabel.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.titleLabel.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.titleLabel.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor].active = YES;
    //[self.titleLabel.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:searchBarTextField.topAnchor].active = YES;

    [searchBarWrapper.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.widthAnchor multiplier:1.0].active = YES;
    //[self.searchBar.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:36.0].active = YES;
    [searchBarWrapper.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.titleLabel.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
    [searchBarWrapper.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
    [searchBarWrapper.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor].active = YES;
    [searchBarWrapper.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor].active = YES;

    [self.searchBar.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:searchBarWrapper.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.searchBar.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:searchBarWrapper.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.searchBar.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:searchBarWrapper.leftAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.searchBar.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:searchBarWrapper.rightAnchor constant:16.0].active = YES;

    return self;
}
```

[image: Left and right spaces highlishted]

The `UISearchBarTextField` is embedded in a `UIView` to which I don't have access to.

The constraints:

[image: The constraints and view hierarchy]

The approach by @BenOng - works fine, but breaks after tapping for the first time:

[image: Tapping]

Comment: [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631567/remove-border-between-view-and-search-bar) original solution worked for me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

UISearchBar have this property `searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment:UIOffset` which you can set to `UIOffsetMake(-8,0)` to make the left side of the text field align with the left edge of the search bar.

Create a UIView right where the full search bar should be and make the search bar it's subview. Set the right edge of the search bar beyond it's super view till the right edge aligns with the superview, it should be about 16 points extra. Make sure the superview's property `clipsToBounds`is set to true, the extra 16 points of search bar background will be clipped.

Comment: Setting `UIOffsetMake(-8,0)` helped to solve the problem with the left offset. But setting a UIView as superview doesn't really work for me. It works at the beginning, but then after tapping the search bar its layout gets recomputed with the extra 16 points blank. Also, you suggested `clipsToBounds`, will make the edges on the right side not round.

Comment: Did you set the constraints correctly? The UISearchBar's original constraint should be applied to the UIView and the search bar made into it's subview with constraint align trailing -16. That should put the trailing edge of the textField along the superview's trailing.

Comment: clipsToBound should only clip the extra space which we push out of the superview away. If part of the textField gets clipped maybe try a larger value instead of -16 as trailing. -16 is only a guess based on the spacing, might be lesser.

Comment: I did all the steps as you described, the search bar looks alright when it gets rendered. But after tapping the search bar for the first time (only the first time), the search field gets displaced (around 8px down, the 16px are missing on the right). Then I rotate the device to rerender the search field after that can tap as many times as I want it works fine. I receive no layout constraint warnings in the console.

Comment: You can check the updated code and added screenshot.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a view below the searchBarWrapper? why is it anchored to self.view? I can't be sure if that is the cause but try setting the bottom constraint of searchBarWrapper to the view below it instead of self.view.

Comment: You mean a wrapper around the wrapper? "Create a UIView right where the full search bar should be and make the search bar it's subview" => that's why `searchBarWrapper` was created there "Shouldn't there be a view below the searchBarWrapper?" => there is `[searchBarWrapper addSubview:self.searchBar];`

Comment: No, I mean there should be since your search bar is at the top of the screen there should be other views between thee search bar and the bottom of the screen no? I think it might help to set constraints to those views instead of the super view

Comment: I'm already doing that, " there should be other views between thee search bar and the bottom of the screen" => the parent view of the search bar including the title view (`SearchBar.m`) is set to fixed dimensions 250x50. That view is set as the `titleView` of the `navigationItem`.