# UIsearchbar show a line below it which never goes

Tags: ios, css, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I have a `UISearchBar` whose bartintcolor i have changed and have cancel enabled. This is added as a subview of a UIVew.
whenever make search bar visible, it shows a black line below it which never goes away.

Am i missing something about UISearchbar appearence or its background view.

```
    dummyview=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30,self.headerView.frame.size.width-20, 30)];
    [dummyview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [dummyview setClipsToBounds:TRUE];
    self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, dummyview.frame.size.width, dummyview.frame.size.height)];
    self.searchBar.delegate = (id)self;
    [self.searchBar setPlaceholder:@"Search"];

    self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
    _searchBar.barTintColor = [Utilities colorWithHexString:@"3a7ebc"];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UISearchBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];


    _searchBar.delegate=self;
    [dummyview addSubview:_searchBar];
```

it gives me like this

[image: Black line color just below]

if i change background to native one, i get displaced content.
`// _searchBar.barTintColor = [Utilities colorWithHexString:@"3a7ebc"];`

[image]

I just dont want the black line below the searchbar.

Updated: 
using
`_searchBar.searchBarStyle=UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
    _searchBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleDefault;`

result in this[image]

So 
finally everything done

`_searchBar.searchBarStyle=UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
    _searchBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleDefault;
    UITextField *searchField=[_searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
    if (searchField) {
        [searchField setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }`

Comment: have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868214/remove-the-1px-border-under-uisearchbar)

Comment: i guess i tried these. Let me try again.

Comment: Change SearchBar Style Minimal in property.

Comment: @KiritModi how. i am not using any storyboards.

Comment: Why you are adding SearchBar in dummyview, You add directly in View and Set Minimal property.

Comment: @Abhijeet_dce, Then Set useing Coding,  searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal

Comment: _searchBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

Comment: searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal

Comment: Dummy view is needed. for functionality.

Comment: 1.  searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default

2. searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal

Comment: @KiritModi yeah. changing that to minimul surely removed my black line.
but now my search bar appearance has changed.
no white color inside the textfield. and text color inside is black.

Comment: What you Say, i dont get..

Comment: @KiritModi
I mean that, changing the barstyle to minimul removed my black line.
my work done.
On the thanks note.. My input field inside uisearchbar background color is changed. and textcolor input is also changed.
updating the screen shot.

Comment: ok, Today I am Answer , how to Change Text field background color, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751292/cannot-change-search-bar-background-color/33751484#33751484

Comment: see this and apply with objective C, in it you put White Color of textfield background.

Comment: crawling to that textfiled not working.

Comment: Updated my answer. its working now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Put my code in viewdidload or viewwillappear method.

```
searchbar.barTintColor=[UIColor samebgcolor];
searchbar.layer.borderWidth = 1;
searchbar.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor samebgcolor] CGColor];
```

Comment: you have samebgcolor to replace your background color value and check?